# How do i align text horizontally between 2 other items in display:flex construction?

Tags: html, css

I need the text to be **centered between** "@" symbols. When text is long, it's wrapped into several lines, so i need *every line* should be centered.
Here's my code (and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o174v2qz/))

```css
.divider {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdb239;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.topic {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.8em + 2.3vw);
}

.topic_symbols {
  color: #ee290b;
}

.topic_text {
  width: 60%;
  color: #3cae3f;
  margin: 1% 3vw 1% 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="topic">
  <div class="topic_symbols">@</div>
  <div class="topic_text">THIS IS THE SAMPLE TEXT WHICH IS LONG</div>
  <div class="topic_symbols">@</div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Comment: Would `text-align: center;` on `.topic_text` do what you want?

Comment: OMG, it was so easy and i can't imagine how i forgot about `text-align` - probably because i've already had a `justify-content: center;` in `.topic` class...? Thank you, it worked!

Comment: OK, I've posted it as an answer then.

Comment: Cool, rated it as an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: center;` on `.topic_text` seems to do the trick.

```css
.divider {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fdb239;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.topic {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.8em + 2.3vw);
}

.topic_symbols {
  color: #ee290b;
}

.topic_text {
  width: 60%;
  color: #3cae3f;
  margin: 1% 3vw 1% 3vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="topic">
  <div class="topic_symbols">@</div>
  <div class="topic_text">THIS IS THE SAMPLE TEXT WHICH IS LONG</div>
  <div class="topic_symbols">@</div>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your text to span over one line between the symbols by making three changes / additions to your `topic` class.

They were:

```
.topic {
  display: grid; // Changed to grid rather than flexbox
/* This allows us to set a column width of min-content for the symbols and let the text grow.*/
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content; 
// Set white-space to nowrap to ensure text only spans on one line.
  white-space: nowrap;
// ...rest of .topic styles
}
```

I hope this helps! Good luck :)